# How tounderstand the proof to show if a real number $w>0$ and a real number $b>1$, $b^w>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers, proof-explanation

Claim: If there are two real numbers $w>0$ and $b>1$, then $b^w>1$.

One proof is that for any rational number $0<r<w$ and $r=m/n$ with $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ and $n\ne0$, $(b^m)^{1/n}>1$. To show $b^m>1$, you can use induction, and then use $1^n=1<b^m$ to finally show that $b^r>1$. So the proof is done.

I do not think this proof is complete. If $w$ is also a rational number, everything is fine. But if $w$ is an irrational number, I think the proof is incomplete, but I am not sure how to proceed.

===========

Please do not use the continuity or more advanced techniques. Assume you just finished the first chapter of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Comment: That raises a question that a surprising number of people simply never consider or take for granted:  how do you define $b^x $ for irrational real $x$, in the first place.  There are many ways to do this, but I think the best way is that for every $x $ there are always sequences of rational $q_n \rightarrow x $.  One can prove that if $q_n \rightarrow x $ then $b^{q_n} $ converges.  If we define $b^x $ as that limit, then this proof for $b^q$ is good enough as if the $b^{q_n}$ are greater than 1 then $b^x $,the limit of those terms, must also be greater than 1.  But you are right.  It's incmpl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly do you define $b^w$ for irrational $w$? If we follow the first chapter of Rudin, then we might use the definition as presented in exercise 6 of chapter 1, which defines

$$ b^w = \sup_{\substack{p \leq w, \\ p \in \mathbb{Q}}} b^p.$$

Then you should show that $b^w$ is an increasing function for rational $w$, and therefore by extension also for all real $w$. Now it suffices to consider $0 < r < w$ as you suggested in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The way to finish that argument is to notice that the function $x\mapsto b^x$ for $x>0$ is an increasing function. You can prove this by elementary calculus (just compute derivative) or simply from the definition (recall that $b^x:=e^{x\log b}$).

To finish your argument then observe that
$$r<w\Rightarrow b^r<b^w.$$

Answer (score 1):

If
$b > 1$,
then
$b = 1+c$
where
$c > 0$,
so
$b^n
=(1+c)^n
\ge 1+nc
\gt 1
$
by
Bernoulli's inequality.

If
$b^{n/m} = a$,
then
$b^n = a^m$.
Since
$b^n > 1$,
$a^m > 1$
so that
$a > 1$.

Then apply the definition
 $b^x
=\sup_{r \le x} b^r
$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need continuity but need concept of convergence.

First realize that you actually don't have any frigging idea what $b^x $ actually *means*.  It's a bit of a shock to me but... it's true.  We have no definition that makes any sense.

But that's okay.  This is a perfect opportunity to define it.  Now that we've read chapter 1 of Rudin we actually know what the real numbers *are* which we didn't before.

Real numbers are the extension of the rationals with the least upper bound property.  So for all real $x $, there is one (many) sequences of rational {$q_n $} such that $q_n\rightarrow x $.

So step 1.  Show that if $q_n <q_{n+1}<... $ converges to $x $ then $b^{q_n}<b^{q_n}<...$ and is bounded above.  I won't do that be its pretty simple.

So simply define $b^x = sup b^{q_n} $.

Step 2.  It's pretty obvious that if $b^{q_n} >1$ then $sup b^{q_n} $ is too.

See Rudin exercise 1.6 for more details.